# How To Update Boost When Yum Has the Outdated Version

Tags: boost, centos, yum, gearman

I am trying to install the latest version of Gearman. However, it keeps giving me the error:

> Checking for Boost Headers version >=
>   1.37... no

When I check my Boost version (yum list installed | grep boost), all the versions are 1.33. The latest Boost version is 1.46, but it seems CentOS does not have this version in their repositories.

Is there any way to get around yum to update Boost to the latest version?

Comment: EDIT: I got around this problem by manually installing an earlier version of Gearman, whose support for Boost was fine with the 1.33 version.

Comment: Did you have any success with your Gearman project? I am trying to get this package working but no love so far. Got me the boost headers but there is another boost error now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try and [build it from source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/more/getting_started/index.html) or add a repo that has the latest boost distro to your yum repos.

Comment: try external repos like centos extras, EPEL, and DAGS (http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/). This may require poking around in /etc/yum.repos.d to enable them or add them (google is your friend)

Answer (score 2):

Download and install earlier versions of Boost from this page: http://www.boost.org/users/history/

Or follow "Ben's" instructions here:

http://ben-tech.blogspot.com/2013/06/build-boost-for-impala-in-centos-63.html

Answer (score 1):

What I did with this is to issue a

`rpm -ql boost-devel` and `rpm -ql boost146-devel`

```
mv /usr/include/boost146/boost /usr/include/boost`
cd /usr/lib/boost/
mv * /usr/lib/
```

Note: just replace the filenames if yours is different